# JTree for desktop application

Tags: java

Iam studying about JTree right now. 
But i don´t know how to render content of choosen JTrees node in e.g. bottom part of my application. 
Lets say i would make application with content - see my picture.

[image]

I know how to make JTree, but how to  manage - if i click on e.g. SUV just bottom part of my application will change the content, JTree remains and upper part as well. still just bottom part changes its content. e.g. suv - info about SUV, CABRIO - info abou cabrio.

```
Do I need another JPanels for upper part which will be stable? 

Do I need another JPanels for botton part which will not be stable?
```

I really need help with this issue, or some link, where can i find answer on my question

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two separate components:

1. A JTree
2. A separate JPanel

You need to add a TreeSelectionListener to the JTree. That will let you know when the user has selected one of the values in the JTree, and you can use that selection to change the contents of the JPanel.

You'll need *another* JPanel for your area labeled, "This part remains the same". You will probably want to put the two JPanels in a JSplitPane with a VERTICAL_SPLIT.

I'm intentionally leaving out some of the implementation details because it looks like you're completing a homework assignment.

Comment: Thak you for your help David  i didnt know how to manage  layout or "organisation" of my application. I want to find implementation by my own  -  but really thank you :)

Comment: You would usually look at JPanel and especially BorderLayout, but in your case, I think you should have two JSplitPane's. Remember that you can "nest" one layout inside another. Also, if you want scroll bars to show up, you need to create a JScrollPane, passing the component you want to be scrollable, then add scroll pane to the layout.